# R Shiny: conditionalPanel with renderUI not working

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to display some UI under conditions. I would like the way to choose input to vary according to the type of data: when the type selected is `Type X`, I want to display a `selectizeInput` and when `Type Y` is selected, I want to display a `sliderInput`. To do so, I use `uiOutput` in `conditionalPanel`.

Here's what I've done so far, following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839815/is-it-possible-to-use-uioutput-in-a-conditionalpanel-in-shiny):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(WDI)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

foo <- data.frame(foo_name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"))
data <- cbind(head(mtcars), foo)

ui <- navbarPage(position = "static-top",

                 tabPanel(title = "Base 1",
                          fluidRow(
                            dropdownButton(

                              selectInput(inputId = "choice",
                                          label = "Type of data",
                                          choices = c("Type X",
                                                      "Type Y"),
                                          selected = NULL,
                                          multiple = FALSE),
                              conditionalPanel(
                                condition = "input$choice == 'Type X'",
                                uiOutput("machin")
                                ),
                              conditionalPanel(
                                condition = "input$choice == 'Type Y'",
                                uiOutput("machin2")
                                ),

                              circle = TRUE, status = "primary", 
                              icon = icon("gear"), 
                              width = "300px",
                              tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Outils")
                            ),
                            column(width = 12,
                                   dataTableOutput("data"))
                          ))

)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$machin <- renderUI({
        selectizeInput(inputId = "test",
                       label = "test",
                       choices = unique(data$foo_name),
                       selected = NULL, 
                       multiple = T)
  })

output$machin2 <- renderUI({
      sliderInput("test2", 
                    "Test2", 
                    min = min(data$hp), 
                    max = max(data$hp), 
                    value = c(min(data$hp), 
                              max(data$hp))
                    )
        })


  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    if(input$choice == "Type X"){
    data2 <- data %>%
      filter(foo_name %in% input$test)
    }
    else if(input$choice == "Type Y"){
      data3 <- data %>%
        filter(hp %in% input$test2)
    }
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Several problems here:

- Both types of inputs are displayed whatever the type of data selected
- when Type X is selected, the dataframe is empty (since the `selectizeInput` is NULL) but when Type Y is selected, some values of the dataframe are displayed

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time first check the help page in R (`?conditionalPanel`) or lookup the function [online](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html). The condition is a JavaScript expression so your $ sign is not working. It should be a . (dot).

```
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.choice == 'Type X'",
  uiOutput("machin")
),
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.choice == 'Type Y'",
  uiOutput("machin2")
)
```