# How to select rows and columns and filter with DT in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt, pickerinput

I am trying to create a Shiny app **capable to select rows and columns** depending on user's choice. For selecting columns I use `pickerInput` and for selecting rows the extension "Select" and more options that you can see in the code (I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046948/exporting-only-selected-rows-from-dt) that it worked perfectly.)

The thing is that **I get this warning** and I think that it is not compatible the type of selections. I am afraid that something that I am not seeing could produce more errors.

*Warning: The Select extension is not able to work with the server-side processing mode properly. It's recommended to use the Select extension only in the client-side processing mode (by setting `server = FALSE` in `DT::renderDT()`) or use DT's own selection implementations (see the `selection` argument in ?DT::datatable).*

On the other hand, I don't know how to hide the "Selection Input" from `pickerInput" and the action button when I select "rows".

This is the code:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinyWidgets)
    library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("type_select", "What do you want to select?",
                   c("Rows" = "Rows",
                     "Columns" = "Columns")),
      uiOutput("picker"),
      actionButton("view", "View Selection")
      
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      h2('Mydata'),
      DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
    )
  )
)

library(shiny)
library(DT)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    iris
  })
  
  output$picker <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = 'pick', 
                label = 'Choose', 
                choices = colnames(data()),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = T)
  })
  
  datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$view,{
    
    datasetInput <- data() %>% 
      select(input$pick)
    
    return(datasetInput)
    
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    if(input$type_select == "Rows"){
        datatable(
          data(),
          selection = "none",
          filter="top", 
          rownames = FALSE,
          extensions = c("Buttons", "Select"),
          
          options = list(
            select = TRUE,
            dom = 'Blfrtip',
            buttons =
              list('copy', 'print', list(
                extend = 'collection',
                buttons = list(
                  list(extend = 'csv', filename = "File", title = NULL,
                       exportOptions = list(modifier = list(selected = TRUE))),
                  list(extend = 'excel', filename = "File", title = NULL,
                       exportOptions = list(modifier = list(selected = TRUE)))),
                text = 'Download'
              ))
          ),
          class = "display"
        )
    }else{
        datatable(
          datasetInput(),
          filter="top", 
          rownames = FALSE,
          extensions = 'Buttons',
          
          options = list(
            dom = 'Blfrtip',
            buttons =
              list('copy', 'print', list(
                extend = 'collection',
                buttons = list(
                  list(extend = 'csv', filename = "File", title = NULL),
                  list(extend = 'excel', filename = "File", title = NULL)),
                text = 'Download'
              ))
          ),
          class = "display"
        )
      }
  })
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Next, I am going to show you some screenshots from the app, to explain how it works.

If you select "rows":
[image: Rows]

If you select "columns":
[image: columns]

In fact, if you want to check if the selection went well, you can download a file (excel, for example) and you will see that your selection is okay.

However, I don't know how to solve the problems that I explained above.

Does anyone can help me, please? I am desperated.

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the entire solution for all the problems:

- Warning (thanks to Ronak Shah's answer)
- How to hide the "Selection Input" from `pickerInput" and the action button when I select "rows". Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839815/is-it-possible-to-use-uioutput-in-a-conditionalpanel-in-shiny).

  ```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyWidgets)
  library(dplyr)

  ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("type_select", "What do you want to select?",
                   c("Rows" = "Rows",
                     "Columns" = "Columns")),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.type_select == 'Columns'",
        uiOutput("picker"),
        actionButton("view", "View Selection")        
      )

    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      h2('Mydata'),
      DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
    )
  )
  )


  library(shiny)
  library(DT)

  server <- function(session, input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    iris
  })

  output$picker <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = 'pick', 
                label = 'Choose', 
                choices = colnames(data()),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = T)
  })

  datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$view,{

    datasetInput <- data() %>% 
      select(input$pick)

    return(datasetInput)

  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(server = FALSE,{
    if(input$type_select == "Rows"){
      datatable(
        data(),
        selection = "none",
        filter="top", 
        rownames = FALSE,
        extensions = c("Buttons", "Select"),

        options = list(
          select = TRUE,
          dom = 'Blfrtip',
          buttons =
            list('copy', 'print', list(
              extend = 'collection',
              buttons = list(
                list(extend = 'csv', filename = "File", title = NULL,
                     exportOptions = list(modifier = list(selected = TRUE))),
                list(extend = 'excel', filename = "File", title = NULL,
                     exportOptions = list(modifier = list(selected = TRUE)))),
              text = 'Download'
            ))
        ),
        class = "display"
      )
    }else{
      datatable(
        datasetInput(),
        filter="top", 
        rownames = FALSE,
        extensions = 'Buttons',

        options = list(
          dom = 'Blfrtip',
          buttons =
            list('copy', 'print', list(
              extend = 'collection',
              buttons = list(
                list(extend = 'csv', filename = "File", title = NULL),
                list(extend = 'excel', filename = "File", title = NULL)),
              text = 'Download'
            ))
        ),
        class = "display"
      )
    }
  })
  }


  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
  ```

Some screenshots after adding the conditionalPanel:

If you select rows...

[image: rows]

If you select columns...

[image: columns]

**WARNING**. This solution doesn't work if you only want to select X number of columns in order to download them (for example, you only want to download 25 entries, but if you download the file you won't have 25 entries, you will have everything.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of warning change `renderDT` to `DT::renderDataTable` and set `server = FALSE` in it.

Here is the complete code -

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("type_select", "What do you want to select?",
                   c("Rows" = "Rows",
                     "Columns" = "Columns")),
      uiOutput("picker"),
      actionButton("view", "View Selection")
      
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      h2('Mydata'),
      DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
    )
  )
)

library(shiny)
library(DT)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    iris
  })
  
  output$picker <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = 'pick', 
                label = 'Choose', 
                choices = colnames(data()),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = T)
  })
  
  datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$view,{
    
    datasetInput <- data() %>% 
      select(input$pick)
    
    return(datasetInput)
    
  })
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(server = FALSE,{
    if(input$type_select == "Rows"){
      datatable(
        data(),
        selection = "none",
        filter="top", 
        rownames = FALSE,
        extensions = c("Buttons", "Select"),
        
        options = list(
          select = TRUE,
          dom = 'Blfrtip',
          buttons =
            list('copy', 'print', list(
              extend = 'collection',
              buttons = list(
                list(extend = 'csv', filename = "File", title = NULL,
                     exportOptions = list(modifier = list(selected = TRUE))),
                list(extend = 'excel', filename = "File", title = NULL,
                     exportOptions = list(modifier = list(selected = TRUE)))),
              text = 'Download'
            ))
        ),
        class = "display"
      )
    }else{
      datatable(
        datasetInput(),
        filter="top", 
        rownames = FALSE,
        extensions = 'Buttons',
        
        options = list(
          dom = 'Blfrtip',
          buttons =
            list('copy', 'print', list(
              extend = 'collection',
              buttons = list(
                list(extend = 'csv', filename = "File", title = NULL),
                list(extend = 'excel', filename = "File", title = NULL)),
              text = 'Download'
            ))
        ),
        class = "display"
      )
    }
  })
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks!! However, do you know if it is going to create problems that the option is false? As I understood reading the warning, it is going to change from server side to client side (and I don't really know what it means)

Comment: Honestly speaking I don't know all the things this could impact but I haven't encountered any issues by doing that.

Comment: I thought that it was working well, but `server=F` produces that I cannot download the files depending on the entries that you have. For example, if you only show 10 entries and you only want to download 10 entries, you cannot do it, since you will download the entire table. 
It was too good to be true.

Thanks anyway